# Loop to save same plot with different highlights using ggplot2

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, gghighlight

I would like to use ggplot to create multiple density plots that have the same data but that show a specific line highlighted.
The table I have is extremely big but has the following columns:

```
Marker  Sample  value
X1      4_HVxLF 0.5
X2      4_HVxLF 0.1
...
```

[image: Here is what I get by plotting all the lines together].

```
ggplot(Dta, aes(x=value, group=Sample, color = Sample)) +
  geom_density()+
  xlab("value")+
  ylab("Density")+
  theme_classic()
```

It is not easy to interpret. Then, My aim is to get something like this: [image: desired plot]. The code used is:

```
ggplot(Dta, aes(x=value, group=Sample, color = Sample)) +
  geom_density()+
  xlab("value")+
  ylab("Density")+
  theme_classic()+
  gghighlight(SampleName == "25_HVxLF",
              unhighlighted_params = list(colour = "grey90"))
```

So I tried building a loop to get a PDF with 4 plots like [the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWvO4.png) per page and for all my samples (105 of them). I cannot used `facet_wrap` because there are too many of them.
Here is what I tried:

```
Samples <- unique(Dta$Sample)    
pdf('Allplots.pdf', width = 8, height = 11)
    par(mfrow=c(4,2))
    for (i in Samples){
      ggplot(Dta, aes(x=value, group=Sample, 
                             color = Sample)) +
        geom_density()+
        xlab("value")+
        ylab("Density")+
        theme_classic()+
        gghighlight(Sample == Samples[i],
          unhighlighted_params = list(colour = "grey90"))
    }
dev.off()
```

But the PDF that comes out is 4kb and I cannot open it. It says there are no pages.
I am not used to work with loops so this is my first attempt ... I don't know what I did wrong (maybe many things), could someone help me figure out ?

Thank you in advance for your kind help !

Diana

Comment: You can use `ggsave()` instead of the graphics device directly. Also `par()` doesn't work with ggplot because it's built on grid; you'll need to subset and use `facet_wrap()` or something like {patchwork}.

Comment: if you could type dput(head(df)) and copy and paste the output into this post it would help us recreate a sample of the dataframe you are looking at

Comment: Could you just add another geom_density call, something like: geom_density(data =. subset(Dta, Samples == "I", aes(x= Dta$Sample), colour="blue")

Comment: Thanks @hachiko for your help. I followed what Stefan said and it worked very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `patchwork` and `lapply` to loop over your samples one approach to achieve your desired result may look like so:

1. Use a first loop to create your plots and store them in a list
2. Use a second loop to glue the plots together in grids of 2 rows and 2 columns using `patchwork::wrap_plots`

Making use of some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gghighlight)
library(patchwork)

plot_fun <- function(highlight) {
  ggplot(Dta, aes(x=value, group=Sample, 
                color = Sample)) +
  geom_density()+
  xlab("value")+
  ylab("Density")+
  theme_classic()+
  gghighlight(Sample == highlight,
              unhighlighted_params = list(colour = "grey90"))
}

Samples <- unique(Dta$Sample)

# Make plots
p <- lapply(Samples, plot_fun)

nrow <- 2
ncol <- 2

# Page counter
idx_page <- rep(seq(ceiling(length(p) / nrow / ncol)), each = nrow * ncol, length.out = length(p))

# Export plots as grids of 2 x 2
pdf('Allplots.pdf', width = 8, height = 11)
lapply(unique(idx_page), function(x) {
  wrap_plots(p[idx_page == x], ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow)
})
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> 
#> [[5]]
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

**DATA**

```
# Random example data
set.seed(123)
n <- 20
Dta <- data.frame(
  Sample = rep(LETTERS[seq(n)], each = 100),
  value = rnorm(100 * n)
)
```

Comment: I do have a question for you. I was wondering why lapply() doesn't follow the order of the string "Sample". The plots drawn in the PDF are not in the order I want. I made sure to reorder both "Samples" and Dta and even reorder the levels of both just in case. And it doesn't follow that order. When looking at the "p" by writing p[[1]], I also see that it starts with the wrong individual and that it corresponds to the first plot. What do you think it can be done to respect the order desired ?

Comment: Hm I general `lapply` will follow the order of the input vector, i.e. `Samples` (I just checked that again.). So, the  only reason (I can think of) why your plots are not in the right order is when `Samples` is not in the right or the desired order. And the reason for that could be that `Dta$Sample` is not in the right order. Without a look at your real data it's hard to figure out a solution. But I would first check the order of Samples.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I tried again ordering `Dta$Sample`. The problem was that `Dta$Sample` was a factor and to be able to use the `order()` function that I was using, it does not work well with factors having different levels. For other people that might encounter that problem, I re-ordered / re-leveled the levels of the factor `Sample` (`Dta$Sample <- factor(Dta$Sample, levels = c("your levels re-ordered as you wish")`) and then used the `order()` function (`Dta<- Dta[order(Dta$Sample),]`). After that, it worked perfectly well ! `lapply()` did put everyting in the order I wanted.